# pause/resume download in my activity by com.mozillaonline

Tags: android, mozilla, download-manager

I'm using open source project for download files 
https://github.com/JiboStore/DownloadProvider

This library worked correctly,

For example this code starting download and show list with pause/resume feature:

`DownloadManager mDownloadManager = new DownloadManager(
                getContentResolver(), getPackageName());
        String url = "....";
        Uri srcUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new Request(srcUri);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("MyApp" + File.separator
            + "Download",
                "test.txt");
        request.setDescription("For test");
        request.setTitle("test.txt");
        mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);`

But I don't know how to use pause/resume within my activity or access to the contents list of downloads for diagnosis item has been paused.

Answer (score 0):

You must in the first access to your downID within database, then handle pause/resume with this:

```
mDownloadManager.pauseDownload(downID);
mDownloadManager.resumeDownload(downID);
```

Comment: Thank's for answer, I had seen the above method but did not know how to get downID. I now realized enqueue method return id. Many thanks for your attention, dear friend.